# Java 8 separate list elements by class

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

given I have a list of items that all inherit from the same base class:

```
class Item {
    protected String name;

    public Item(String name) {

        this.name = name;
  }

  getName() {

      return name;
  }
}

class ItemA extends Item {...}
class ItemB extends Item {...}

List<Item> itemList = Arrays.asList(new ItemA("itemA"), new ItemB("itemB"));
```

In my case I have no control over how these classes are implemented but I need to separate the list into two different lists containing the name of the respective element.

Here is the first try at a solution that contains lots of `if` and `instanceof` statements:

```
List<String> itemAList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> itemBList = new ArrayList<>();

itemList.forEach(item -> {

    if(item instanceof ItemA) {

        itemAList.add(item.getName());
    }        
    else if(item instanceof ItemB) {

        itemBList.add(item.getName());
    }
});
```

So this works but I gave it some thought on how to avoid the `if` statements. Since I'm using Java 8 I can do this:

```
List<String> itemAList = itemList.stream()
    .filter(ItemA.class::isInstance)
    .map(item -> item.getName())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<String> itemBList = itemList.stream()
    .filter(ItemB.class::isInstance)
    .map(item -> item.getName())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This works as well but it means I have to process the list two times.

As I said I have no bearing on the implementation of the `Item` classes so what would be the best way to implement such a behavior?

Greetings

[edit:] Thank you for all the responses. I've learned something new today.

Comment: `Collectors.partitioningBy` if you know for a fact that there are only two types, if not `Collectors.groupingBy`

Comment: @Naman if you know that there are two types only, there is a specialized map of only two possible keys inside the stream api; but otherwise I updated the comment

Comment: @Eugene the only reason I'd pointed that out(before the comment edit) was that partitioning uses a `Predicate` and the condition of saying class would either be `ItemA` or anything else isn't extensible further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can group the content based on the class of the elements :

```
Map<Class, List<String>> grouped = itemList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getClass,
                Collectors.mapping(Item::getName, Collectors.toList())));
```

and access it as:

```
List<String> itemAList = grouped.get(ItemA.class);
```

Comment: Mind that `getClass` and `instanceof` are not doing the same if `ItemA` or `ItemB` have been subclasses…

Comment: Thank you, for your help. This cleaned up my code significantly.

Answer (score 2):

As you said you have different instances you have no control over, so you can't really be sure that only `ItemA` and `ItemB` occur in the list.

You're better of using a map, which has the name as the key and a `List` of `Item`s as values:

```
Map<String, List<Item>> map = itemList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getName, Function.identity()));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also do :

```
Map<Boolean, List<Item>> classMap = itemList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(ItemA.class::isInstance));
```

which outputs

> ```
>  {
>     false=[ItemB [getClass()=class stackoverflow.ItemB]],
>     true =[ItemA [getClass()=class stackoverflow.ItemA]]
>  }
> ```